# How to run my script that starts a UI on startup in the new PIXEL desktop environment?

Tags: raspbian, pixel

I have a script ~/startup.sh that invokes a GUI program.  I want this script to run once during user login (not everytime when a new terminal is opened).  How to achieve this?

I have tried lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart changes but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by placing a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart/`.

Comment: Could you please add this as the correct answer.